# pinnedHeaderListView not showing headers for "exotic" characters

Tags: android, header, android-listview, scroll

I'm using the cool example of [pinnedHeaderListView](https://code.google.com/p/android-playground/) and I wish to use it for all kinds of strings.

For some reason, some characters (like '~') do not show well there and cause their header not to be shown.

[image]

As you can see, there is no header for "~" . If I scroll until the first item shown has a "~", the header is shown.

Why does it occur, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look it seems like this is the cause:

line 131 on PinnedHeaderActivity.java is your issue
    this.mIndexer = new StringArrayAlphabetIndexer(objects, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

try adding the ~ char to your alphabet.

Comment: no it isn't the cause . i've already made it flexible and accept any character based on the input of objects . i think it's inside the implementation itself.